# Getting System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. in Google URL Shortener API Call

Tags: c#, google-api, google-url-shortener

I am using below code to shorten long urls

```
public static string UrlShorten(string url)
{
    string post = "{\"longUrl\": \"" + url + "\"}";
    string shortUrl = url;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + ReadConfig("GoogleUrlShortnerApiKey"));
    try
    {
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = post.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
            requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    shortUrl = Regex.Match(json, @"""id"": ?""(?<id>.+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // if Google's URL Shortner is down...
        Utility.LogSave("UrlShorten", "Google's URL Shortner is down", url, ex.ToString());
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return shortUrl;
}
```

I have created a scheduler to shorten large number of urls. And most of the time of got below exception

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I was thinking that due to Courtesy Limit i was getting this exception so increased Per-User Limit by 100,000.0 requests/second/user but still I'm getting the same exception.

I don't understand why its happening even i am making hardly 2000 request to the server at a time.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you see what the whole json response is? not only the status code.

Comment: It throws the exception at "using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())" and the complete execption is "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()      at BusinessLogic.Utility.UrlShorten(String url) in D:\Dotnet Projects\FutureZoom\FutureZoom\BusinessLogic\Utility.cs:line 140"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your question I presume it's a rate-limit exceeded error. You can retrieve the error response if you modify your code like this:

```
try
{
  ........
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
   string responseText;

   using(var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
     responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ......
}
```

If it's a rate limit exceeded error you will find something like this in `responseText`:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am getting the exactly same response. But why its coming even i increased the Per-User Limit by 100,000.0 requests/second/user and Courtesy Limit is 1,000,000 requests/day

Comment: I can't guess what it exactly is, but maybe you are doing to much request per second? Otherwise try contact Google.

Comment: My total request are less than 2000.

Comment: Does it take time to reflect the Courtesy Limit ?

Comment: Can be the case, whats your dashboard saying? https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: dashboard says http://www.futurezoom.com/google_dashboard.png and Quotas says http://www.futurezoom.com/google.png

Comment: Strange, I don't know why, try contact google or google forum.

Comment: I have seen the same problem post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-url-shortener/The$20remote$20server$20returned$20an$20error:$20(403)$20Forbidden/google-url-shortener/MxSaCV143vg/ky1QG_skBVUJ but didn't get the solution.

Comment: Its working now. It took time to update the limit and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error occuring because your posting the data to webservice very fastly so google detecting it as robot.(if you post data manually this frequently it will ask to enter captcha code ).

so to resolve this problem you need to increase time interval between each post request.